# Angular: limpiar input filtro tras búsqueda

Tags: angular

tengo 2 filtros input para hacer búsquedas de ID. Tengo también un botón de inicio para resetear y que vuelva a cargar todos los datos tras la búsqueda. Los datos los carga bien, sin embargo no me "limpia" la búsqueda en el input dejando la opción por defecto, es decir se queda puesto lo que he tipeado para la búsqueda. Me gustaría que tras dar al botón reinicio el input quedara también con la opción por defecto.
¿Alguna idea?

**html**

```
<form  (ngSubmit)="Filtros()">
<div>
                    <label for="ids">Ids: </label>
                    <input name="idsValue" id="idsValue" placeholder="Ids"(keyup)="IdPed($event)">
                </div>


 <input type="submit" value="Reinicio" id="sub_but" (click)="reset()">

</form>
```

**ts**

```
  IdPed(event)
  {
     this.idsValue=event.target.value;
  }

reset(){


       this.idsValue= '';
   

    
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo que añadas un ngModel:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wnj5ky?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```
<div>
  <label for="ids">Ids: </label>
  <input
    name="idsValue"
    [(ngModel)]="idsValue"
    id="idsValue"
    placeholder="Ids"
    (keyup)="IdPed($event)"
  />
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Reinicio" id="sub_but" (click)="reset()" />
```

Comment: Funcionó! Muchas gracias!